# Can I define and use global variables within content fields?

Tags: variable, globals, content

I'd like to set a variable like "totalCustomers" and then use this throughout our content in different pages and content blocks so that there is one source of truth. Is that possible?

e.g. I define a global variable "totalCustomers" = "10,000"

Then within a new entry I can use this in the heading, something like "We serve [global.totalCustomers] customers daily"

And then in another entry I can use this in some other content "Our [global.totalCustomers] love us"

Answer (score 1):

You can use reference tags:
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/reference-tags.html#examples
E.g:

1. Create a Global Set with handle `customers`
2. Create a `totalCustomers` field and assign to said Global Set
3. Save value to `totalCustomers` field.
4. Then use the following ref:
   `{globalset:customers:totalCustomers}` as a placeholder on any text field.
5. When you render the field you'll need to call the `parseRefs` filter:

```
entry.myField | parseRefs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use like this. but there is way with twig replace.
you can use same keyword as above `[global.totalCustomers]` in your heading or any field. then in twig template query the global and replace this with original count in frontend.

```
{% set globalCount = globalhandle.totalCustomers %}
{{ entry.heading|replace({'[global.totalCustomers]': globalCount}) }}
```